# Limit length of several text fields

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextfield

I have several text fields in one view controller and I'm using the following function to limit the number of characters:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    return textView.text.characters.count + (text.characters.count - range.length) <= 300
}
```

How can I change the number of maximum number of characters for a different text field? I need a lower limit for another text field.

Comment: use tag for those textfields

Comment: if you can elaborate how to do that would be great

Comment: Do you have those textFields connected to an IBOutlet?

Comment: yes I have create an outlet for each text field

Comment: Just add a switch statement

Comment: for textfield shouldChangeIn function?

Comment: Are you using text view or text field?

Comment: I have 2 text views and one text field

Comment: Damn... I know were the error now

Comment: Make use of Tags

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield?language=swift you need to use another method for your text fields

Comment: Yeah Thanks that the thing I actually  need a different method for TextField.

Comment: First of all you need a function to properly count the characters of the input. i.e if your input is "hello", characters.count will do the job but some emojis will give you a count of 2-3 characters for one emoji. Once you have that function then use tags as others have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

For TextView you need to use following TextView delegate method

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool
{
     if textView == yourTextViewName
     {
         let str = (NSString(string: textView.text!)).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
         if str.characters.count <= 300 {
             return true
         }
         textView.text = str.substring(to: str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 300))
         return false
     } 
     return true
}
```

For TextField you have to use following delegate method

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    if textField == yourTextFieldName {
        let str = (NSString(string: textField.text!)).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        if str.characters.count <= 300 {
            return true
        }
        textField.text = str.substring(to: str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 300))
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

I hope this help you.